# Oracle SQL Practice

Tags: sql, oracle

So I'm super stuck on a practice problem I'm on while reading through my book. This is the requirement:

List the zip code, name and phone number of instructors who teach students that live in same zipcode as the instructor.

And this is the expected results:
FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME PHONE

---

Nina Schorin 2125551212
Todd Smythe 2125551212
(2 Rows)

This is the code I have so far and I return two results just not the correct results. Any help would be much appreciated.
I added an Image of the Tables and queries that I'm working with.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT S.first_name, S.last_name, S.PHONE
    FROM STUDENT S, ENROLLMENT E, section SE, INSTRUCTOR I
    WHERE S.STUDENT_ID = E.STUDENT_ID 
    AND E.SECTION_ID = SE.SECTION_ID
    AND SE.INSTRUCTOR_ID = I.INSTRUCTOR_ID
    AND S.ZIP = I.ZIP
    GROUP BY S.FIRST_NAME, S.LAST_NAME, S.PHONE
    MINUS
    SELECT DISTINCT I.first_name, I.last_name, I.PHONE
    FROM STUDENT S, ENROLLMENT E, section SE, INSTRUCTOR I
    WHERE S.STUDENT_ID = E.STUDENT_ID 
    AND E.SECTION_ID = SE.SECTION_ID
    AND SE.INSTRUCTOR_ID = I.INSTRUCTOR_ID
    AND S.ZIP = I.ZIP
    GROUP BY I.FIRST_NAME, I.LAST_NAME, I.PHONE;
```

[TABLES AND RESULTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUjWx.jpg)

Comment: I think you are studying a wrong book, because you still have not learned how to use JOINS instead of the comma-separated tables in the `FROM` clause

Comment: The book is Oracle SQL by Example by Alice Rischert, Prentice Hall/Pearson Education Fourth Edition. I'm sure it's not the book that is the problem, it's more likely my understanding of it :)

Comment: Please post data as formatted text, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link for you, this'll make you understand better way: [SQL INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

And here's what you should code:

```
select INSTRUCTOR.FIRST_NAME, INSTRUCTOR.LAST_NAME, INSTRUCTOR.PHONE, STUDENT.FIRST_NAME, STUDENT.LAST_NAME 
from INSTRUCTOR inner join STUDENT on INSTRUCTOR.ZIP = STUDENT.ZIP
```

I put it **Student's first name and last name** so you have a better idea to who that instructor teaches.